# Deleting an App from another app in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an app live on app store. Due to some reasons i am about to push new app on app store, and want to uninstall old app from new app. Is there any way to uninstall/delete an iOS app from user's iPhone.

Comment: Impossible for an app store app.

Comment: I just want to know that any how? can we make two iOS applications in such way that one application can be uninstalled/deleted from another application?

Comment: Thankfully, this is impossible...

Comment: Why don't you just have the new app replace the old app?

Comment: if you explain your reasons, we might be able to show you alternatives.

Comment: @user4923464 I specifically stated that it's not possible. Asking a 2nd time doesn't change the answer.

Comment: This is not a single app, there are five application for five different countries, having different languages. Now instead of managing five different apps I am making single app (which will support more than five countries) which will be configured based on user’s location (at first launch). If user downloaded new app and he/she has old app as well it may create some confusion.

Comment: When your new app is approved by Apple, remove the other apps from the App Store. Then new users can't download the old apps.

Comment: And what about old users, We don't want negative comments from them. @rmaddy, Thanks for reply.

Comment: They can't leave a review for an app that isn't in the store.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, due to iOS not allowing people access to the file system. The only thing you can do, with an `itms-services://` link, is prompt the user to download an app available somewhere for ad-hoc delivery.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to have much to do with the question. It's not possible because a 3rd party app can't delete other 3rd party apps. It has nothing to do with what the user has access to. And this question has nothing to do with ad-hoc delivery.

Comment: I agree completely with your second sentence. I only offered the ad-hoc delivery explanation as an example to show the person who asked the question how limited 3rd party access to the iOS filesystem is.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the current bundle identifier to the new app and submit as an update. It doesn't matter if it's the same project or a new one. As long as bundle identifier stays the same it will count as update.

This won't technically uninstall the old app, but it will look like it did.
Just remember that scheduled notifications and persisted files will remain as they were, you will have to implement some clean up logic to get rid of them.

Comment: Agreed but I will have to manage old apps(five different apps) and new app as well. I want a single app to replace all the apps.

Comment: You can pull those other apps from the store, that's the best you can do here. And of course push a small update to them, blocking the content and guiding to your new app